# iOS 12 Shortcuts App - Possible to toggle specific notification settings?

Tags: python, automation, ios12, sirishortcuts

Device: iPhone X;
OS: iOS 12.0;
Application: Shortcuts

Goal: Using Shortcuts, create a workflow to turn off notifications for one specific application. (Example: Start Script, turns off notifications for Mail app)

Since iOS 12 dropped this week, I've been playing with the Shortcuts app for automating workflows. It seems to get pretty deep with options for scripting, and various system actions, but I cant seem to find a way to target specific application notifications. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish something like this?

I'm considering buying Pythonista for $10, since python scripts can be utilized in Shortcuts, but would prefer to be sure it could ultimately accomplish my goal.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and thoughts! :)

Answer (score -1):

It appears that you can indeed use the new Shortcuts feature with Phythonista. I've not tried this myself but there are some Reddit articles on the matter.

According to [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/9gpa2h/shortcuts_pythonista_information_sharing/), you can do:

- You can launch python scripts using Run Script
- You can pass arguments and access them with `sys.argv`
- Shortcuts pauses the current workflow and waits until the app is returned to
  *You can get back to Shortcuts using `webbrowser.open('shortcuts://run-shortcut?name=My%20Shortcut')`

There is also [a video](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/9mf0b6/shortcut_and_pythonista/)

And according to [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/9hgblf/pythonista_and_shortcuts/), there is a free alternative called [Scriptable](https://scriptable.app/) which is JavaScript instead of Python.

Thanks very much for this question which has prompted me to experiment some more with Shortcuts and discover these tools.

Comment: This answer does not respond to the question "Possible to toggle specific notification settings?". From what I have seen online, it is currently not possible to change notification settings for specific apps.